# Development folder structure on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos

I have switched to Mac as my main development machine (coming from Fedora) and was just curious as to what people used as there development folder structure. For example in Fedora I always had ~/opt for user programs ~/src for source code I was working on and ~/bin for files I constantly executed. Is there a Mac de facto. What do you guys perfer?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: I saw you can create an ~/Applications dir and Mac treats it like the /Applications. I am not sure if that just means you get the "A" on the directory or some kind of symlink is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 3 folders in home:

**Sandbox** - my source control checkouts

**Dev** - projects that are not in source control (tests, experiments, etc.)

**3rdPartyDev** - 3rd party code I've downloaded and want to keep around

I try to keep as much 3rd party code around as possible. With the Mac's Spotlight feature, you can instantly search all the code at once.  If there's an API I need to see example code for, I just Spotlight for it and chances are some code in there is already using it.

Comment: How does OS X handle an Applications folder if you create it in ~? Is it user only or is it somehow linked to /Applications?

Comment: Where do you put bsh scripts you create?

Comment: @gsieranski: ~/Applications is a distinct directory from /Applications. It is (somewhat) special if you create it, as you can see from the special icon that appears. Just a clutter-reducing choice on Apple's part that it isn't created by default.

Comment: I just keep commonly used shell scripts in the home folder to they're accessible when I open a new Terminal window. I should probably put them somewhere else and include that in $PATH but I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 9):

I use the directory `~/Developer` as the root of my development-related files. Inside that I have `~/Developer/Code` for code snippets, tutorial code, test ideas, etc. I have a `~/Developer/Projects` directory to hold in-development projects. This contains a few subdirectories, including `Archives` for projects I've abandoned, and `Current` for current development work. `~/Projects` is also a symlink to `~/Developer/Projects/Current`.

Comment: Mac seems to have a capitalized directory structure. Us linux guys are lazy and like lower case :)

Answer (score 5):

To add to @mipadi, after a recent fresh install of OSX 10.10.2 (Yosemite) I noticed that if you create a `~/Developer` folder, that folder automatically receives a special folder icon (with a hammer on it). This property seems to be an artifact of older versions of Xcode, in which it would automatically create the folder for you.

Comment: Works on Catalina as well.

Comment: Works on Monterey as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have a big messy folder called "code" full of Xcode projects.

Comment: Yea, I would like to keep things more separated and organized :)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, for all developer projects there is a specific folder inside the home directory called `~/Developer`, which when you create automatically has a customised icon.

You can thus subdivide using this:

- Experiments: things you just want mess around with.
- Public: open source
- Private: private projects
- Learning: If you're on a learning path to track your progress and milestones.

[image]